# add new columns in data frame by subtracting column from a list

Tags: r

I have a large data set and i  want to loop over the results, subtract column as present in a list  and output the result for each row in a new column.

```
ref1 <- samples   Controls
       E_2334188 E_2334207
       E_2334202 E_2334221

df1 <- 
      Chr  Start End    Feature         E_2334188   E_2334202   E_2334207    E_2334221
      1 740001 760000 1:740001-760000    1.6832013  0.8346011  -0.23045394  1.5974912
      1 760001 780000 1:760001-780000   -0.3231613 -1.8504905   0.13668752 -0.38662600
      1 780001 800000 1:780001-800000   -0.3936060 -2.2163153  -0.15266541 -0.60706691



ind <- which(names(df1) %in% ref1$samples)
rnd <- which(names(df1) %in% ref1$controls)

    df2 <- df1[,c(1:4)]  
    df2$newcol <- 0

    for (i in 1:nrow(ref1)){
        n <- df1[ind]-df1[rnd]
        df2$newcol[i] <- n
    }
```

expected outcome

```
df2 <- 


         Chr  Start End    Feature         E_2334188   E_2334202   
          1 740001 760000 1:740001-760000    1.913655  -0.7628901  
          1 760001 780000 1:760001-780000    -0.4598488    -1.463865
          1 780001 800000 1:780001-800000   -0.2409406 -1.609248
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset the 'df1' based on the elements in 'samples' and 'Controls', subtract them, and `cbind` with the first 4 columns of 'df1'.

```
cbind(df1[1:4],df1[ref1$samples]- df1[ref1$Controls])
#   Chr  Start    End         Feature  E_2334188  E_2334202
#1   1 740001 760000 1:740001-760000  1.9136552 -0.7628901
#2   1 760001 780000 1:760001-780000 -0.4598488 -1.4638645
#3   1 780001 800000 1:780001-800000 -0.2409406 -1.6092484
```

NOTE: If the 'samples' and 'Controls' columns are `factor` class, convert to `character` and use the same approach.

```
cbind(df1[1:4],df1[as.character(ref1$samples)]- df1[as.character(ref1$Controls)])
```

Comment: i have a large dataset. with 74 columns, for easy understanding i subset the data

Comment: @beginner It doesn't really matter.  If you have column names in the 'samples' and 'Control's from the 'ref1', this is basically subsetting corresponding columns from 'df1' and subtracting equal sized datasets.

Comment: @beginner Here I am assuming that the columns on the same row (column names) of 'ref1' should be subtracted.